# What's wrong with scanf + getchar + printf

Tags: c

I can't figure out what is wrong with this piece of code:

```
scanf("%d", &intVal);  
charval= getchar();
printf("Integar: %d\nCharacter: %c\n", intVal, charVal);
```

The question stipulates that the input given was 100 A.
Also, it seems to me the problem is that entering 100 A leaves off the character. But i'm not sure what the actual problem with the code is.

Comment: Maybe as `getchar` retruns `int` and `charVal` is `char` .

Comment: Kind of hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code.  I thing the above may be right

Comment: `charval` become `' '`, but this  expect the `'A'`.

Comment: Oh! I get it now! Thanks so much BLUEPIXY

Comment: @ameyCU `charVal` has no data type in that example ... so your assumption doesnt make much sense - `%c` can also take an `int` as input, for example - thats valid syntax

Comment: also typo `charval` <=> `charVal`

Comment: @specialist  Correct we were making assumption as we don't know its type .Thast why my sentence starts with 'maybe'.

Comment: Have you actually try to run the code... Might tell you directly that the error is that the character A is not captured. Please put some effort into the task before asking your question on SO

Answer (score 5):

Well, first things first, in one place you have used `charval` and in another you have used `charVal`, however, I suppose this is a transcription error. The real problem is that, it doesn't work! The below code with the input you specified doesn't capture the character.

```
int main() {
    int intVal;
    char charVal;

    scanf("%d", &intVal);  
    charVal= getchar();
    printf("Integar: %d\nCharacter: %c\n", intVal, charVal);  
}
```

outputs:

```
./a.out
100 A
Integar: 100
Character:
```

Note, you cannot type `100` followed by a space and then `A`, since `getChar()` then picks up the space, not the A. So in order to allow this to occur, you can change the `scanf` line to `scanf("%d ", &intVal);` OR change your input to `100A`

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question perfectly. And yes, It was a transcription error.

Comment: Minor: Better to use `int charVal` as `getchar()` typically returns 1 of 257 different values and those cannot be distinctly stored in a `char`.